# Does RenderSection() work inside ASP.NET Core's <environment> tag-helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Layout has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <environment names="Development">@RenderSection("devCss", required: false)</environment>
  <environment names="Staging,Production">@RenderSection("staproCss", required: false)</environment>
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()
  <environment names="Development">@RenderSection("devJs", required: false)</environment>
  <environment names="Staging,Production">@RenderSection("staproJs", required: false)</environment>
</body>
</html>
```

View has this:

```
@section devCss { <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" asp-append-version="true" /> }
@section staproCss { <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.min.css" asp-append-version="true" /> }
@section devJs {}
@section staproJs {}

<h1>hello</h1>
```

When `RenderSection()` is outside the `<environment>` tag, everything works.

When inside, as in above example, it fails with the unhelpful error of `InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '_Layout.cshtml': 'staproCss, staproJs'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").`

That obviously makes no sense, as all sections were defined. And it complained about some, and not the others.

**Does the `<environment>` tag-helper allow `RenderSection()` within it?**

Comment: Only those sections matching the environment are defined at runtime. You will need to add corresponding environment checks before rendering content to the each section.  For example, <environment names="Development">
    @section devCss{
        This is the dev stuff
    }
</environment>

Comment: @user2818985 That makes sense. The environment that isn't defined will not emit the stuff within, which causes the child view to fail. If you add that as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is thanks to a comment by @user2818985.

The environment which is not defined, will not emit the content within. Which means it won't emit the `RenderSection()` call. Which means the view will define a `section foo { ... }` which doesn't exist. Which fails, and thus the exception.

To accomplish my original goal, I updated the layout:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment _env
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <environment names="Development">
        @RenderSection("devCss", required: false)
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        @RenderSection("staproCss", required: false)
    </environment>
    @if (_env.EnvironmentName == "Development" && IsSectionDefined("staproCss"))
    {
        IgnoreSection("staproCss"); 
    }
    @if (_env.EnvironmentName == "Staging,Production" && IsSectionDefined("devCss"))
    { 
        IgnoreSection("devCss"); 
    }
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <environment names="Development">
        @RenderSection("devJs", required: false)
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        @RenderSection("staproJs", required: false)
    </environment>
    @if (_env.EnvironmentName == "Development" && IsSectionDefined("staproJs")) 
    { 
        IgnoreSection("staproJs"); 
    }
    @if (_env.EnvironmentName == "Staging,Production" && IsSectionDefined("devJs")) 
    { 
        IgnoreSection("devJs"); 
    }
</body>
</html>
```

So the sections are always defined, and so the child views never throw.

Comment: I don't think the `_env.EnvironmentName == "Staging,Production"` comparison will work since the environment will either be Staging _or_ Production ... not both. You'd need a function to check that the real environment name (`_env.EnvironmentName`) exists in the comma separated list.

Comment: Rather than putting those if tests at the end with the _env vars , you can put the if in each of the environment blocks and just test if the section is defined.

Answer (score 13):

Just Add `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` in end of `</body>` tag.

Comment: I have the same problem and your answer helped me....insted of "Scripts" I used "footer" to render NavBar

Comment: Thanks. I was able to render the pages that replace the default Identity.UI. Unfortunately they are loaded outside the single App page.. But hey, better than nothing :)

Comment: nice ,,, thnx mate

Answer (score 1):

No, the environment tag is used to render different HTML based upon the environment defined by the ASPNET_ENV environment variable. For example, a different set of CSS definitions can be used for a development environment as compared to a production environment.

This link may also be helpful: 
[A Complete Guide to the MVC 6 Tag Helpers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers/)

You can use the environment variable value in your website logic as shown here.
[image]

See this link for more information: [Working with Multiple Environments](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html)

Comment: I understand how the `<environment>` tag-helper works, and its purpose. The question is whether it allows a `RenderSection()` within it? I'd expect so, but I get exceptions.

Comment: PS, the example you gave, is exactly what my question is about. :)

Comment: I extended my answer to address the implied goal of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a view that implements the `_Layout` file and also implements a Scripts file.

You just need to add this line just before your `</body>` tag.

```
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: I'd like to add that all scripts and styles that the view implements while also implementing from the layout file, we will need to add that script you mentioned. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
All scripts and styles that the views implement while also implementing the layout file will need either one of these lines added